# How can I share a class between GWT client code and server code?

Tags: java, gwt

Is it possible to "share" a Java class between GWT client code and server code?

I have a simple class that just holds a few `Strings` and a few `List<String>`'s.  I'd like to be able to use this class in both client side code and server side code just for some consistency.

Just to give some background, the class I'm trying to share is just a container for an error message with some extra info.  In my application there are some errors that prevent a save so we do those checks on the client side (before saving).  Then after saving, we do more "validation" checks on the saved object on the server side.

I understand that it would have to be "compiled" twice, once for the GWT compile and once for the normal javac compile, but it seems like that should be possible.

Is there a way to set up my GWT project to do this?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

One of the reason of using GWT is to have single domain model for client and server.

It is a common practice to have shared classes between server code and client side.

Usually project with GWT client source code splits up to three packages

```
com.yourpackage
               -shared
               -client
               -server
```

where `shared` package compiles both to java byte code and javascript, `client` to javascript, and server side logic is placed in `server` package.

Compilation path for client can be configured in `*.gwt.xml` file.

Comment: The standard for GWT is to use the name `shared`. That being said, good answer. +1

Comment: Thanks Mairbek, this worked for me.  Just to be a little more specific, we didn't have a "shared" package so I had to create a new package.

I also had to add a line to my *.gwt.xml file: `<source path='shared'/>`